# Excel will not input value into cell

Tags: vba, excel

I am having an issue updating the value of a cell. Below is a test code I am running to just ensure I can update a cell value. There are no errors but the cells remain empty upon running the code.

Edit: I'm not very versed in the vba syntax so I have updated the code below to show what I am attempting to do. Basically I want to find a value corresponding with a certain material, then sum all values found. I know you say I am not inputting values but instead am pulling them. I believed I was initializing the variable. How do I input the value instead?

```
Sub MaterialSort()

Dim deut As Double
Dim am241 As Double
Dim pu238 As Double
Dim pu239 As Double
Dim pu240 As Double
Dim pu241 As Double
Dim np237 As Double
Dim u238 As Double
Dim u235 As Double
Dim u233 As Double
Dim am243 As Double


deut = Worksheets("Material PEC").Cells(2, 2).Value
am241 = Worksheets("Material PEC").Cells(3, 2).Value
pu238 = Worksheets("Material PEC").Cells(4, 2).Value
pu239 = Worksheets("Material PEC").Cells(5, 2).Value
pu240 = Worksheets("Material PEC").Cells(6, 2).Value
pu241 = Worksheets("Material PEC").Cells(7, 2).Value
np237 = Worksheets("Material PEC").Cells(8, 2).Value
u238 = Worksheets("Material PEC").Cells(9, 2).Value
u235 = Worksheets("Material PEC").Cells(10, 2).Value
u233 = Worksheets("Material PEC").Cells(11, 2).Value
am243 = Worksheets("Material PEC").Cells(12, 2).Value


For j = 2 To 82 Step 8
For i = 3 To 70

    k = j + 5

If Not IsError(Worksheets("Master PEC").Cells(i, j)) Then

    If Worksheets("Master PEC").Cells(i, j) = "Deuterium" Then

        deut = Worksheets("Master PEC").Cells(i, k).Value + deut

    ElseIf Worksheets("Master PEC").Cells(i, j) = "Am-241" Then

        am241 = Worksheets("Master PEC").Cells(i, k).Value + am241

    ElseIf Worksheets("Master PEC").Cells(i, j) = "Pu-238" Then

        pu238 = Worksheets("Master PEC").Cells(i, k).Value + pu238

    ElseIf Worksheets("Master PEC").Cells(i, j) = "Pu-239" Then

        pu239 = Worksheets("Master PEC").Cells(i, k) + pu239

    ElseIf Worksheets("Master PEC").Cells(i, j) = "Pu-240" Then

        pu240 = Worksheets("Master PEC").Cells(i, k) + pu240

    ElseIf Worksheets("Master PEC").Cells(i, j) = "Pu-241" Then

        pu241 = Worksheets("Master PEC").Cells(i, k) + pu241

    ElseIf Worksheets("Master PEC").Cells(i, j) = "Np-237" Then

        np237 = Worksheets("Master PEC").Cells(i, k) + np237

    ElseIf Worksheets("Master PEC").Cells(i, j) = "Dep. U-238" Then

        u238 = Worksheets("Master PEC").Cells(i, k) + u238

    ElseIf Worksheets("Master PEC").Cells(i, j) = "Enr. U-235" Then

        u235 = Worksheets("Master PEC").Cells(i, k) + u235

    ElseIf Worksheets("Master PEC").Cells(i, j) = "U-233" Then

        u233 = Worksheets("Master PEC").Cells(i, k) + u233

    ElseIf Worksheets("Master PEC").Cells(i, j) = "Am-243" Then

        am243 = Worksheets("Master PEC").Cells(i, k) + am243

    End If

End If
Next
Next
End Sub
```

Comment: You are not **putting values into** cells; you are **getting values from** cells.

Comment: You are just overriding the variables with a new value. You never actually update the values

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your assignments are not done correctly. What I would do is:

```
Dim deut As Double
deut = 2
Worksheets("Material PEC").Cells(2, 2).Value = deut
```

and so on...

Comment: thanks! just mixing up my left and right over here, don't mind me

Answer (score 1):

This should work

```
Sub MaterialSort()

Dim deut As Double
Dim am241 As Double
Dim pu238 As Double
Dim pu239 As Double
Dim pu240 As Double
Dim pu241 As Double
Dim np237 As Double
Dim u238 As Double
Dim u235 As Double
Dim u233 As Double
Dim am243 As Double

deut = 2
am241 = 2
pu238 = 1
pu239 = 3
pu240 = 3
pu241 = 4
np237 = 5
u238 = 12
u235 = 4
u233 = 4
am243 = 5

Worksheets("Material PEC").Cells(2, 2).Value = deut
Worksheets("Material PEC").Cells(3, 2).Value = am241
Worksheets("Material PEC").Cells(4, 2).Value = pu238 
Worksheets("Material PEC").Cells(5, 2).Value = pu239
Worksheets("Material PEC").Cells(6, 2).Value = pu240
Worksheets("Material PEC").Cells(7, 2).Value = pu241 
Worksheets("Material PEC").Cells(8, 2).Value = np237
Worksheets("Material PEC").Cells(9, 2).Value = u238
Worksheets("Material PEC").Cells(10, 2).Value = u235
Worksheets("Material PEC").Cells(11, 2).Value = u233
Worksheets("Material PEC").Cells(12, 2).Value = am243


End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are setting the current value to a variable then setting a new value to that variable and never actually updating the cell itself.

To put code into the cell it should look something like this

```
duet = 2
Worksheets("Material PEC").Cells(2, 2).Value = deut
```

Answer (score 0):

The code that you have posted in your question is not assigning a cell a value.  In the first block you are assigning the variables values from the cells and in the second block you are reassigning them.

You will need to have range and double variables instead of just double variables in order to do what I think you want to do.

```
Sub MaterialSort()

Dim deut As Double
Dim am241 As Double
Dim pu238 As Double
Dim pu239 As Double
Dim pu240 As Double
Dim pu241 As Double
Dim np237 As Double
Dim u238 As Double
Dim u235 As Double
Dim u233 As Double
Dim am243 As Double

Dim deut_rng As Range
Dim am241_rng As Range
Dim pu238_rng As Range
Dim pu239_rng As Range
Dim pu240_rng As Range
Dim pu241_rng As Range
Dim np237_rng As Range
Dim u238_rng As Range
Dim u235_rng As Range
Dim u233_rng As Range
Dim am243_rng As Range

set deut_rng = Worksheets("Material PEC").Cells(2, 2)
set am241_rng = Worksheets("Material PEC").Cells(3, 2)
set pu238_rng = Worksheets("Material PEC").Cells(4, 2)
set pu239_rng = Worksheets("Material PEC").Cells(5, 2)
set pu240_rng = Worksheets("Material PEC").Cells(6, 2)
set pu241_rng = Worksheets("Material PEC").Cells(7, 2)
set np237_rng = Worksheets("Material PEC").Cells(8, 2)
set u238_rng = Worksheets("Material PEC").Cells(9, 2)
set u235_rng = Worksheets("Material PEC").Cells(10, 2)
set u233_rng = Worksheets("Material PEC").Cells(11, 2)
set am243_rng = Worksheets("Material PEC").Cells(12, 2)



deut = Worksheets("Material PEC").Cells(2, 2).Value
am241 = Worksheets("Material PEC").Cells(3, 2).Value
pu238 = Worksheets("Material PEC").Cells(4, 2).Value
pu239 = Worksheets("Material PEC").Cells(5, 2).Value
pu240 = Worksheets("Material PEC").Cells(6, 2).Value
pu241 = Worksheets("Material PEC").Cells(7, 2).Value
np237 = Worksheets("Material PEC").Cells(8, 2).Value
u238 = Worksheets("Material PEC").Cells(9, 2).Value
u235 = Worksheets("Material PEC").Cells(10, 2).Value
u233 = Worksheets("Material PEC").Cells(11, 2).Value
am243 = Worksheets("Material PEC").Cells(12, 2).Value


deut_rng.value = 2
am241_rng.value = 2
pu238_rng.value = 1
pu239_rng.value = 3
pu240_rng.value = 3
pu241_rng.value = 4
np237_rng.value = 5
u238_rng.value = 12
u235_rng.value = 4
u233_rng.value = 4
am243_rng.value = 5

End Sub
```

This saves the original values of the cells into all of the double variables and then allows you to change the values in the cells using the range varaibles.